# Magento after pull custom module on server, custom block not showing template

Tags: git-pull, magento-1.9.1

I was created custom module what perfect works on local server, but after pulling it on the remote server, the template wasn't shows on frontend. If I change in layout type of block to standart core/template it's showing in hints, but if put again my type module/block it is not working. Repeat, that code  same as on local server and remote server. And all other functionality working fine.

Comment: Was that template added and committed first? Is it ignored? (`git check-ignore -v -- mytemplatefile`)

Comment: no, template was added in the commit. With git was all good. Today I'm tryed to recreate this files with other names and it's working now. Some strange situation, but I resolved it by recreation of block file with another name.